# Are the Android manifest device-filtering options broken or am I missing something?

Tags: android, manifest

I was trying to prevent users from downloading my app on devices that are clearly incapable of running it (it's a Unity3D game), and figured I'd use android:glEsVersion and screen size as a filter to get rid of the worst of them.

With the following two lines in my manifest, Google Play filters my list of compatible devices down to (a surprisingly low) 905 valid devices:

```
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="false" android:normalScreens="false" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
```

(Without them, I get 4489 valid devices)

One of the devices that gets removed is my own Nexus 5, but it has OpenGLES 3.0 support and a resolution way above the definition for "largeScreen", so it makes no sense to me at all.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on? GooglePlay does not say why a given device is excluded, so it's kind of hard to backtrace.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that will work, but did you try to add

```
          android:anyDensity="true"
```

But in https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html#manifest we can see :

```
If your application uses OpenGL features that are not available on all devices
```

Comment: android:anyDensity is true by default and according to the docs should never be set to false. I'm not sure what that link you provided is supposed to tell me, except that what I did was correct and should limit devices to those supporting OpenGL ES 2.0 and above?